# python 3-Requests: Staying logged in website

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with requests.Session() as c:
    body = {'username':'*****','password':'*********','submit':'Log  In','mod':'www','ssl':'0','dest':'community'}
con = c.post('https://secure.runescape.com/m=weblogin/login.ws', data=body)
a = (con.cookies['session'])
cookies = dict(session=a)
b = c.get('https://www.runescape.com/c=Xbn439ejpJo/account_settings.ws?jptg=ia&jptv=navbar',cookies=cookies)
```

With the first link I manage to login. When I try to reach the second page, I am not logged in... why?
    print (b.text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the login tokens of the website. Runescape is a popular game, and so they may have dozens of method of preventing scraping like what you seem to be trying to do.

Other than that, the normal method that logins use is to use a session id - which is sent in the header of every request. You've already added the cookie for this - so this doesn't seem to be the problem.

The way you can debug this is to open a browser and see the raw request it sends using the debugging tool (chrome and firefox have one). And mimic the request you see there i python.

Would be good to set the "origin" header to Chrome or similar so that Runescape doesnt auto detect that it's being scraped.

---

**Note** : Always check the ROBOT.txt and don't go against their policies while doing this. They can easily ban your IPs and accounts if you do that.

Comment: I do not even play that game ( I have an account tho) because I found it easy to test my requests scripts in it (search options, logins, modify account,etc.). I see what you are saying but see it like this: In the get request I asked to get to a certain url but it redirected me to the formal login page, is there a way to accept the redirect and answer the fields and go to the get page requested?